# Forcing the combat in Warhammer: Invasion

Tags: warhammer-invasion

I've been playing several games of Warhammer: Invasion Core Set with my friend and a couple of times we've encountered a situation where he had pretty good attack force set up in his battlefield and I has good one as well. But I already had one district burning and he had bunch of damage tokens on two of his districts.

So what I wanted to do in this situation is to attack his forces so his chances for gathering enough strength to finish me off would be smaller. I've attacked his battlefield and what he usually did is he didn't set any defenders and allowed the whole damage to be dealt to his district (even if it meant burning it down). Then in his turn he launch his full force agains one of my other districts and burn it down thus winning the game.

I was wondering are there any cards or rules in this game or it's expansions that would force him to fight me instead of letting all the damage to be dealt to his capital? This would allow for more tactical approach in my opinion because right now his best tactics is to ignore all my attacks and hope to get stronger force to destroy a district in one round then me.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defending you quest and kingdom zones enough.  There is no reason for him to attack your battlefield if your defenses are weak in the other two zones.  It's better for him to attack those and win than fight your battlefield.